# Can't disable reformatting code when on save files in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.4 delete whitespaces when saving files.
I set:
Settings > Tools  > Actions on Save: All checkboxes disabled
Settings > Editor > Code Style > Formater > Do not format: *.{html,hbs,js,json,py}
Settings > Editor > General > Remove trailing spaces on: disabled
but IntelliJ still change files on each save.

Comment: Okay. This is not the place to report bugs for intellij though.

Comment: Please open "Settings | Editor | General", and check your "On Save" setting.